# How does Anomaly detection in Elasticsearch work?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a question about the Anomaly Detection module provided by elastic stack. As per my understanding of Machine Learning the more data being fed to the model the better learning it will do provided the data is proper. Now I want to use the Anomaly Detection Module in kibana. I did some testing with that and with some reading I found that basically it is better that we have at least 3 weeks of data or 20 buckets worth. Now lets say we receive about 40 million records a day. This will take a whole lot of time for the model to train for a day itself now if get about 3 weeks worth of this amount of data this will put a lot of pressure on the node. But if I feed the model less data and reduce the bucket span it will make my model more sensitive. So what is my best bet for this. How is that I can make the most out of the Anomaly Detection module.

Just FYI: I do have a dedicated Machine learning Node with equipped with more than enough memory but it still takes a whole lot of time to process records for a day so my concern is it will take a whole whole lot of time to process 3 weeks worth of data.

So My question is that if we give large amount of data for short amount of time say 1 week to the model for training and if we give large amount of data for a slightly longer amount of time say 3 weeks to the model for training will these two models detect anomalies with the same accuracy.

Comment: Can you define "it still takes a whole lot of time to process records". What is a lot of time for you? hours, days, weeks?

Comment: Well for about 24 hours of data which is roughly around 30 -35 million records it took about 4 - 4.5 hours.

Comment: That's quite fast :-) Ok, so for three weeks, we're talking ~80 hours, it can be a lot... or not... it's all relative and it depends on what your goals are. Anyway, I have an answer ready if you're interested

Comment: Yeah Sure. Will appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a dedicated ML node with ample memory, I don't see what the problem could be. Common sense has it that the more data you have, the better the model can learn, and the more accurate your prediction model will be. Also seasonality might not be well captured with just one week of data. If you have the data and are not using it out of fear that it will take a "some time" to analyze it, what's the point of gathering it in the first place?

It is true that it will take "some time" to build the model **initially**, but afterwards, the ML process will run more frequently depending on your chosen bucket span size (configurable) and process the new documents that arrived in the meantime, it's really fast. Regarding sensitivity, your mileage may vary, but it's not dependent only on the amount of data you feed, but also on the size of the bucket span you choose.

Comment: Ok, So if we initially scan 3 weeks worth of data then go ahead and delete that data and then set the rollover policy that only 1 week worth of data will be stored. this won't affect my ml job in any way right? I am guessing it won't as it has already scanned the docs. Am I correct here?

Comment: Correct, the data is analyzed by ML in chronological order and is only needed once at model creation time. The cumulative model for that old data is stored in the .ml-state index. The only downside is that if you need to run another job on that data (with other detectors and/or other influencers) and you don't have the data anymore, it won't be possible.

Comment: Ok Thanks, Apprecite it man big help